# Possible Memory Leak Issues in NestWhile

Tags: bugs, core-language, memory

Consider the following code snippet:

```
NestWhile[{#[[1]]+1,Pause@.001;ConstantArray[0,{100, 100}]}&,
  {1}, (#[[1]] <= 10000) &, 2]
```

In theory, when evaluating, `NestWhile` shall keep track of the last two results generated, thus consuming approximately 160kB of memory.

However, in reality, memory consumption will continue to grow at a pace of approximately 80MB/s before `NestWhile` finishes calculation. Furthermore, regardless of the fourth parameter (as long as it is not 1), the speed of memory consumption is the same. These two phenomena indicate that Mathematica evaluates the expression and stored all results in memory until all computations are finished then picks out last two elements.

This behavior is rather disturbing for me: why save the previous evaluation results in memory if they are used in nowhere?

---

This behavior exists in v12.0 and v11.2

---

## Update

Received reply from technical support which said:

> This behavior of storing all intermediate steps of a calculation is
>   intended. Clearing intermediate information that has been stored can
>   be done with the command `ClearSystemCache[]`

However, after altering the code to:

```
NestWhile[(ClearSystemCache[]; {#[[1]] + 1, Pause@.001; ConstantArray[0, {100, 100}]})&,
  {1}, (#[[1]] <= 10000) &, 2]
```

still cannot stop fast increasing memory consumption during evaluation.

Furthermore, a new observation, when evaluating this piece of code, Mathematica will eventually consume 99% of memory, but will not try to use virutal memory. So theoretically this behavior will not influence the performance of Mathematica, however, if I open another program, Mathematica will encounter memory related issues sometimes and crash. But by all means, I think consuming all memory is not a good choice.

Also, if Mathematica actually saves all these intermediate steps for acceleration of evaluation, then why Mathematica do not store them when the fourth argument is 1? I'm still a bit confused with this reply...

---

Update 2

Received another reply from technical support after explaining that clearing cache will not help and this behavior did no good to any evaluation while causing memory explosion.

> I have sent a suggestion report to the appropriate people in our
>   development team so changes to how NestWhile handles memory can be
>   considered for future versions of Mathematica.

Hope this bug can be fixed in the next version of Mathematica...

Now, before this problem is solved by Wolfram officially, let this question be:

### "How to implement a efficient `myNestWhile` which works exactly as `NestWhile`?"

Comment: I added a comma in your code, now it runs.

Comment: To watch the memory being used, add a [`Monitor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Monitor.html) with `Monitor[NestWhile[{#[[1]] + 1, Pause@.001; x = MemoryInUse[]; ConstantArray[0, {100, 100}]} &, {1}, (#[[1]] <= 10000) &, 2], x]`

Comment: My rather uneducated guess would be that `NestWhile` has been implemented through `NestWhileList`. If you record the `x` values for both versions (with `NestWhile` and then with `NestWhileList`), and plot their differences, the result is pretty much a constant of size 185Kb in favor of `NestWhile` (while the absolute numbers are hundred of Mbs). In other words, their memory consumption patterns are exactly the same.

Comment: @Roman Thanks for correcting the code! Also the memory monitor code is a great add-on for the question.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Yes, @happy fish and I guessed like this as well when we first encounter this issue. But this behavior is truly not desirable. Or maybe the question shall be why `NestWhile` is designed in this particular way, are there any hidden advantage of this implementation?

Comment: @Wjx I agree that this behavior is totally not desirable. My guess is that this was the easiest way to ensure that `NestWhile` and `NestWhileList` are fully consistent with each other, since they share the same code path. I will make an internal suggestion to do something with this (chances are that this issue is already known internally and is on someone's todo list).

Comment: Maybe contact support and suggest an improvement? Clearly, it doesn't *need* to be this way, but implementing it like this is much easier considering what the 4th and 6th arguments do.

Comment: Yes, considering the possibility of negative 6th argument, simply saving everything is the easiest way... but making improvements to take this into consideration is not that hard as well I guess? I will try to contact support and clarify this issue, but I believe @Leonid Shifrin 's internal suggestion will take effect sooner~

Comment: @Wjx "but I believe Leonid Shifrin 's internal suggestion will take effect sooner" - not necessarily. Generally, external reports and suggestions may have more weight, particularly if there are a number of reports requesting this.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Seemingly you are right... I do get a reply from support in almost no time... ;)

Comment: This appears to be an issue with ParallelTable aswell. But Table works correctly. This might be a rather fundamental bug in most functions.

Comment: @Gladaed No, this is specific to `NestWhile`. The concept doesn't even apply to other functions ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Executing this Lambda with ParallelTable gives me a constantly and seemingly unstopping rising memory usage.

Comment: @Gladaed That's not a very precise description ... If you think there's a problem, make sure you set `$HistoryLength = 0`, and open a new question with a complete minimal example.

Answer (score 8):

This works without hogging memory:

```
nestWhile[f_, expr_, test_, m_Integer:1, max_:∞, n_Integer:0] /; m>=1&&n>=0 := 
  Module[{c = m - 1, r = NestList[f, expr, m - 1]},
    While[test @@ r && c++ < max, r = Append[Rest@r, f@Last@r]];
    Nest[f, Last@r, n]]
```

In contrast to the real [`NestWhile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html), the above does not implement the following:

- `NestWhile[f,expr,test,All]` supplies all results so far as arguments for `test` at each step.
- `NestWhile[f,expr,test,{mmin,m}]` does not start applying test until at least `mmin` results have been generated. At each step it then supplies as arguments to test as many recent results as possible, up to a maximum of `m`.
- `NestWhile[f,expr,test,m,max,-n]` returns the result found when `f` had been applied `n` fewer times.

Suggestions and improvements highly welcome!

Comment: I fear that this might have certain impact on the performance of `NestWhile`? My simple test using code `nestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, #2 < 1000000 &, 2]; // Timing` shows that this code is approximately three times slower than the original `NestWhile`. So maybe there's still room for improvements.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm shocked by the insanely slow speed of `NestWhile`, in comparison, `Nest[# + 1 &, 1, 1000000]` only takes 11ms. a 100 times decrease in performance...

Comment: @Wjx I've made some minor speed improvements, but at the core I think that my rewrite of `nestWhile` is simply much slower than `NestWhile`. When the functions `f` and `test` are a bit more complex, this overhead won't matter much.